# Correct syntax to access .each tr with a variable as the table selector

Tags: jquery, datatables

Just learning the world of jquery, and all my googling gives examples like this:

```
$('#example thead tr').each( function () {}
```

If I have a variable instead of "#example", how do you do the same kind of loop?  This is what I'm trying to accomplish, but can't find any examples anywhere to explain how to use the methods with a variable instead.

```
var rows = oTable.$("tbody tr)"); // skip the header row
rows.each(function(index) {
    console.info("Got here");
    oTable.insertBefore(  nCloneTd.cloneNode( true ), this.childNodes[0] );
} );
```

The code above runs with no errors, but the console.log never appears.

Here's what initializes the table variable:

```
function initTable ()
{
    var myTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bStateSave": false,
        "sAjaxSource": 'example_arrays.txt',
        "bRetrieve": true
    } );
    return myTable;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 $.each( oTable.$("tr"), function(index){
     console.info("Got here");
     oTable.insertBefore(  nCloneTd.cloneNode( true ), this.childNodes[0] );
 });
```

Comment: BINGO...this is the syntax I was trying to find on google (didn't know the correct terms.)...This causes the loop to now be entered, but it only loops once.  You've answered my question, but any thoughts on why it's only occuring for 1 row, when the rendered table has 15 rows?

Comment: @GDP What will be in your console, when you will do `console.log($("tbody tr",oTable))`?

Comment: It logs:  jQuery(tr.odd).   Another confusing aspect of learning jquery and Datatables....it magically creates the table with a lot of automatic jquery interaction

Comment: @GDP Sorry, I didn't know much about `dataTable`s. I just know jQuery's syntax.However I have researched the dataTables API, and provided new answer.Check it.It should do what you need.

Comment: How wonderful...the insertBefore does not work, but the loop DOES, so you've answered the question again! :)  (Wish I could accept twice).

Comment: @GDP As I mentioned earlier, I am not familiar to `dataTables`,but familiar to jQuery. My advice to you, research the docs of `dataTable API`,only then you could reveal the problems

Comment: Might be onto something....the console.log is ONLY encountered in the loop if i have a breakpoint in the script before the loop....is there a timing aspect that i need to learn about?

Comment: You've been most gracious with your time - i truly appreciate most helpful assistance.

Comment: @GDP ['fnInitComplete'](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnInitComplete) callback could be interesting for you.

Comment: That triggered all sorts of wonderful things that has ultimately solved all my problems on this....thank-you, thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

remove the ")" bracket and oTable in your code and check $("tbody tr)"); . try this code

```
 var rows = $("tbody tr"); // skip the header row
 rows.each(function(index) {
   console.info("Got here");
   oTable.insertBefore(  nCloneTd.cloneNode( true ), this.childNodes[0] );
  } );
```

Comment: But oTable is the variable with the rows in it - how will your code "know" that?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your row variable is not empty.
Also, why did you remove the #example from the selector ?

Comment: The table variable isn't empty, it shows as expected.  The example code I'm working from does use $('#example'), but it never entered the loop, thus my attempt to work from the variable.